# How to Upgrade Ghost Script to the latest version?

Tags: 10.04, installation, ghostscript

I have default ghostscript version 8.71 installed in my Ubuntu Machine i would like to update it to the latest version

I download the file from http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostpdl-9.01.tar.gz
When i run make command i get error

```
o -c ./obj/gsromfs1.c
./obj/echogs -w ./obj/ldt.tr -n - gcc  -o ./bin/gs
./obj/echogs -a ./obj/ldt.tr -n -s ./obj/gsromfs1.o ./obj/gs.o -s
cat ./obj/ld.tr >>./obj/ldt.tr
./obj/echogs -a ./obj/ldt.tr -s - -ldl -lm  -rdynamic -ldl  -lpthread -lm
if [ x != x ]; then LD_RUN_PATH=; export LD_RUN_PATH; fi; \
XCFLAGS= XINCLUDE= XLDFLAGS= XLIBDIRS= XLIBS= \
FEATURE_DEVS= DEVICE_DEVS= DEVICE_DEVS1= DEVICE_DEVS2= DEVICE_DEVS3= \
DEVICE_DEVS4= DEVICE_DEVS5= DEVICE_DEVS6= DEVICE_DEVS7= DEVICE_DEVS8= \
DEVICE_DEVS9= DEVICE_DEVS10= DEVICE_DEVS11= DEVICE_DEVS12= \
DEVICE_DEVS13= DEVICE_DEVS14= DEVICE_DEVS15= DEVICE_DEVS16= \
DEVICE_DEVS17= DEVICE_DEVS18= DEVICE_DEVS19= DEVICE_DEVS20= \
DEVICE_DEVS_EXTRA= \
/bin/sh <./obj/ldt.tr
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/gs] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext`. Pay attention to `-lXext`, this means that the linker tried to link the objects to the `Xext` library. For that to work, you need to have the `libxext-dev` package installed.

Generally speaking, to solve errors like `cannot find -lNAME`, install the `libNAME-dev` package.